# Undo a previously resolved merge conflict resolution?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

Say I have a feature branch and was rebasing from a devlopment branch and ran into a merge conflict. Instead of including both the content from the development branch and the content from my feature branch during conflict resolution, I mistakenly chose to keep only the content from the feature branch.

Now when I go to merge the feature into the development branch git will do a fast-forward merge which is desired, however, all the content from the development branch that I did not include in the rebase merge resolution will now be removed from the devlopment branch. This continues to happen even if I do a hard reset of the head of the development branch back before the merge.

How can I reset gits 'recollection' so to speak of the mistaken way that I had resolved the conflict?

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is how git works... Probably the easiest way to handle this, is to find your old commit, then redo the rebase.

When doing a rebase, you make new commits, but your old commits are normaly not deleted. You can find the hash of your old commits using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Newest items are on top. Just scroll down until you find the head commit of the old branch.

When you have the hash of you old commit, just do a hard reset on this commit.

`git reset --hard <your_commit_hash>`